# Golang mongo-go-driver Beta 1 , using greater than operator

Tags: go, mongo-go

I have been trying to get records greater than an **_id** provided
The code is below

```
filter = bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"$gt": "5c1760b4bd421c09e0f3140c"}}
cur, err := collection.Find(ctx, filter, &options)
```

But iam always getting null values.
I think i need to convert that id to object id
But iam not sure how to do it in latest release
There is a bson.TypeObjectID shown in predictions . Can someone please provide some details to do this.? Thanks

Comment: try wrapping id in bson.ObjectIdHex() e.g. bson.ObjectIdHex("5c1760b4bd421c09e0f3140c") and see if it works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to compare `ObjectID` to `ObjectID`. What you are doing is comparing an `ObjectID` to a `string`.

```
objectID, _ := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex("5c1760b4bd421c09e0f3140c")
filter = bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"$gt": objectID}}
cur, err := collection.Find(ctx, filter, &options)
```